# LINQ start and stop segments in list of List<T> elements

Tags: c#, linq, sequence, morelinq

Given a list of objects of one class (`List<Type1>`)

```
item1.isbool = true, beat = 1
item2.isbool = true, beat = 1.333
item3.isbool = true, beat = 1.666
item4.isbool = false, beat = 2
item5.isbool = false, beat = 3
item6.isbool = false, beat = 4
item7.isbool = false, beat = 5
item8.isbool = true, beat = 5.333
item9.isbool = true, beat = 5.666
```

I would like to get the starting and stopping values in the tuplet group (of variable sizes) to add to a list of a second class (`List<Type2>.Add()`)

```
item1.tuplet = start
item3.tuplet = stop
item8.tuplet = start
item9.tuplet = stop
```

The order of the elements do matter.  MoreLinq as an option, but not certain of the type of operation I need to perform to get those values.  It could be either a Partition or some sort of GroupBy, but that doesn't seem to work.

My end results I need at the end are going to be

```
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.Start});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.None});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.Stop});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.None});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.None});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.None});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.None});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.Start});
List2.Add(new Object() {Tuplet = TupletType.Stop});
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to do.  It would be helpful if you could post code that would actually compile and maybe any attempts that you've made at solving your problem.

Comment: The working code I have to get to that sequence is a bit too interconnected to get there.  I'll add a bit to show what I am expecting instead.

Comment: I'd just iterate through the list with a for loop, no need for linq. If you find a 'true' save it as start. Run until the next one is a false. If so, set it as stop.

Comment: So given a list of objects that have a `bool` property, you want to return a `Tuple` that contains the object and a `bool` where the objects are the start and end of runs within the list of the property being `true` and the corresponding `bool` value in the `Tuple` would tell you if the object was the start or end of said run?

Comment: @juharr I need to add all of the elements of the first sequence and tag certain ones that start and stop subsequences.

Comment: @Carra would that mean I set the element as a variable outside of the loop?

Comment: @Manchuwook If you need to mutate the objects in the list, then Linq isn't the best option.  Just do it in a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an extension method to do the grouping, then you can use:

```
List<Type1> runs = ...

List<Type2> grouped = new List<Type2>();
grouped.AddRange(runs.GroupByRuns());
```

Here is a possible solution for the extension method:

```
public static class GroupType
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type2> GroupByRuns(this IEnumerable<Type1> sequence)
    {
        if (sequence.Count() == 0)
            yield break;

        List<bool> next_items = sequence.Select(s => s.isbool).ToList();
        next_items.Add(false);

        bool previous_item = false;
        int idx = 1;
        foreach (var item in sequence)
        {
            if (item.isbool)
            {
                if (previous_item == false)
                {
                    yield return new Type2 { Tuple = Type2.TupletType.Start };
                }
                else if (next_items.ElementAt(idx) == true)
                {
                    yield return new Type2 { Tuple = Type2.TupletType.None };
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return new Type2 { Tuple = Type2.TupletType.Stop };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new Type2 { Tuple = Type2.TupletType.None };
            }
            previous_item = item.isbool;
            idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with one for loop.

```
Type1 start;
Type1 stop;

for (int i=0; i<list.Length; i++)
{
  if(start == null && list[i].isbool)
    start = item[i];
  if(start != null && (i+1 == list.Length) || !list[i+1].isbool)
  //no next item or next item is false? Found the stop.
  {
    stop = item[i];//Found a start & stop, add them to a list
    start = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I add them both at the `//Found a start & stop, add them to a list` between `stop = item[i]` and `start = null`, the items will be out of order.  Also, do the regular non-tuplet items go outside the two `if` statements?